# X axis rotation of a canvas ui joystick element doesnt work while Y axis does in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to rotate a joystick that has an arrow image. The thing is that the joystick can rotate on the Y axis while it cant rotate on X. I couldn't figure out why this happens. Thanks.

```
    if (Touch.TouchDist.x > 0)
    {
        Bow.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(Bow.transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, -90f), 10f * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if (Touch.TouchDist.x < 0)
    {
        Bow.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(Bow.transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 90f), 10f * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if (Touch.TouchDist.y > 0)
    {
        Bow.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(Bow.transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, -90f),10f* Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if (Touch.TouchDist.y < 0)
    {
        Bow.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(Bow.transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 90f),10f* Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "joystick can rotate on the Y axis while it cant rotate on X" it sounds like it's a malfunctioning :)

Jokes aside, it's not clear what your intentions are, but your code have some issues that can simply be improved and you may archieve what you are looking for if you change your code to this (be aware that the rotation will have acceleration):

```
if (Touch.TouchDist.x != 0)
{
    Bow.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(Bow.transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 90f * Touch.TouchDist.x), 10f * Time.deltaTime);
}
if (Touch.TouchDist.y != 0)
{
    Bow.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(Bow.transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0f, 90f * Touch.TouchDist.y, 0f),10f* Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Further more, if you want to the gameobject to rotate at both directions at the same time, check this:

```
if (Touch.TouchDist.x != 0)
{
    float y = Bow.transform.rotation.Euler.y;
    Bow.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(Bow.transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0f, y, 90f * Touch.TouchDist.x), 10f * Time.deltaTime);
}
if (Touch.TouchDist.y != 0)
{
    float z = Bow.transform.rotation.Euler.z;
    Bow.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(Bow.transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0f, 90f * Touch.TouchDist.y, z),10f* Time.deltaTime);
}
```